# Convert Multiple Rows into Single Column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, grouping

I have this huge data of books of various publishers, some record in 4 lines some in 5 some in 3, each record ends with an empty cell, which looks like this:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
emptyCell
5555
6666
7777
8888
9999
emptyCell
1234
5678
9999
```

What formula/macro code can be used to get the output of:

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
5555 6666 7777 8888 9999
1234 5678 9999
```

[image: I have data in the format, image link below]

Comment: You should take a moment to read the [help] then [edit] your question to show what you have already tried, and what error you might get. SO is not a code writing service but a place to come for help when you have something to show for your troubles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following VBA code to transpose data with spaces. This will not remove the original code.

```
Sub Transpose()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Set rng = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
j = 1
For i = 1 To rng.Row Step 5
Cells(j, "B").Resize(1, 5).Value = _
Application.Transpose(Cells(i, "A").Resize(6, 1))
j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

[source](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/41909-transpose-macro.html)

Comment: Downvotes should not be used as you think someone shouldn't be answering a question. Up voted to balance out

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Sucks when you get penalized for providing a legitimate answer. I appreciate you.

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you for your kind effort and help, thanks @n8_ for providing the desired code

Answer (score 2):

one of the possible solutions:

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1))
    Dim cl As Range, key As Variant, strToAdd$: strToAdd = ""
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Value2 <> "" Then
            strToAdd = strToAdd & " " & cl.Value2
        Else
            dic.Add strToAdd, Nothing
            strToAdd = ""
        End If
    Next cl
    Dim sh As Worksheet, i&: i = 1
    Set sh = Worksheets.Add: sh.Name = "Result"
    For Each x In dic
        sh.Cells(i, "A").Value2 = x
        i = i + 1
    Next x
End Sub
```

*test based on provided dataset:*

[image]

**UPDATE: in case when the results in a row should have their own cell**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1))
    Dim cl As Range, key As Variant, strToAdd$: strToAdd = ""
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Value2 <> "" Then
            strToAdd = strToAdd & "|" & cl.Value2
        Else
            dic.Add strToAdd, Nothing
            strToAdd = ""
        End If
    Next cl

    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets.Add:
    Dim x, y$, z&, i&: i = 1
    sh.Name = "Result " & Replace(Now, ":", "-")

    For Each x In dic
        y = Mid(x, 2, Len(x))
        For z = 0 To UBound(Split(y, "|"))
            sh.Cells(i, z + 1).Value2 = Split(y, "|")(z)
        Next z
        i = i + 1
    Next x
End Sub
```

*test based on provided dataset:*

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that the results in a row should have their own cell but it’s not totally clear

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 in such case it can be easily modified using `split()` function, I will add this variant, maybe you are right

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub DataTranspose()
    Dim NoRows As Long, CurrentRow As Long, OffsetColumn As Long
    Dim ResetCurrentRow As Long, ResetOffsetColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Replace with your destination. This will start writing back to Row 1 Column B
    ResetCurrentRow = 1
    ResetOffsetColumn = 2

    ' Replace with reference to your sheet
    With ActiveSheet
        NoRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        CurrentRow = ResetCurrentRow
        OffsetColumn = ResetOffsetColumn

        For i = 1 To NoRows
            If .Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                .Cells(CurrentRow, OffsetColumn).Value2 = .Cells(i, 1).Value2
                OffsetColumn = OffsetColumn + 1
            Else
                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                OffsetColumn = ResetOffsetColumn
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried all possible solutions provided, but the data in the result of this code coming in one row, but what I want the data one row for each entry and for the next entry to start from next row. Like I mentioned in my question.

But the results coming through all above-mentioned codes are like this:

1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 1234 5678 9999

Comment: If they’re all presenting the date incorrectly I think you need to be clearer in what you expect the output to be. Also, If all your results are in one row from my answer, then the empty cells aren’t empty

Comment: my data is like given in this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJISv.jpg

Comment: @Tom and Asif, I have tried all the codes now and all of them works with the data your provided Asif. It wouldn't be any different with the image you provided, All the codes will behave the same (except Vasily but he clearly shows that). In your data at row 5, Is it **completely** empty (no hidden **spaces** in cell A5)?

Comment: Yes, after the first entry 5 row is empty, but still, after running the code all data coming in one row, it's not shifting to the next row for each entry

Comment: Sounds strange, very strange! If you don't mind, could you please share a dropbox link with your **raw data**, with the first 20 rows as in your picture and I will happily take a look at your data and revise my code if I see anything strange :)

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted the question as the cell values should have their own cell when they are copied to the row.

You need to define which workbook name, worksheet names and also which column the result should start and paste into (`columnComparePaste = 2 'where 2 = Column B`).

This is a possible solution then.

**VBA Code**

```
Sub CompareCopyFilter()

Dim CopyFromWorkbook As Workbook
Set CopyFromWorkbook = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm") 'Name the Workbook that should be copied from
Dim CopyToWorkbook As Workbook
Set CopyToWorkbook = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm") 'Name the Workbook that should be copied to
Dim CopyFromSheet As Worksheet
Set CopyFromSheet = CopyFromWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name the Worksheet that should be copied from
Dim CopyToSheet As Worksheet
Set CopyToSheet = CopyToWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name the Worksheet that should be copied to
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lrowCompare As Long
Dim lrowPasteCopyTo As Long
Dim Val As String
Dim ValCompare As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Test As String
Dim Test2 As String
Dim columnComparePaste As Long
Dim columnCompare As Long

columnComparePaste = 2 'Which column number the data should be past into (Column B = 2)


lrow = CopyFromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in sheet that should be copied from
lrowCompare = CopyToSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in sheet that should be copied from
columnCompare = columnComparePaste 'Dummy variable to reset column number

For i = 1 To lrow 'Find last row in the range you want to copy from
Val = CopyFromSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value 'Get the value from the cell you want to copy from
    If Val <> "" Then 'If cell is not empty then
            CopyFromSheet.Activate 'Activate worksheet to copy from
            CopyFromSheet.Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "A")).Copy 'Copy cell from column A, row i
            CopyToSheet.Activate 'Activate worksheet to paste into
            CopyToSheet.Range(Cells(lrowCompare, columnCompare), Cells(lrowCompare, columnCompare)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste cell from into Column set earlier, add 1 column for each loop
            columnCompare = columnCompare + 1 'When value is pasted to column, add 1 column for next loop to paste into
    Else
    lrowCompare = lrowCompare + 1 'For each empty cell add one row below previous to paste into
    columnCompare = columnComparePaste 'Reset the column value where paste should start
    End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deselect any copy selection
End Sub
```

Result in Excel:

[image]